# input a piece of text in a table

Tags: tables

I have a big table, which is hard to manage once I start filling in the cells. I would like to write something like `\include{text_i_j}` in each cell and write the corresponding code for the text outside of the table.

An example would look something like this:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c |}
 \include{text_1_1} & \include{text_1_2} & \include{text_1_3} \\ 
 ...
 \include{text_10_1}  & \include{text_10_2} & \include{text_10_3}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\define{text_1_1} Text 1 1
\define{text_1_2} Text 1 2
...
```

To get the following result:

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: \input not \include to include a file but you just want `\newcommand` I think.

Comment: ...see [When should I use `\input` vs. `\include`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246/5764)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Is the problem the underbar? `\verb|Text_i_j|` will preserve the underbars, although if uses tt font.  \url{...} from the url package will probably work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\include` is a command for including files, and always starts a new page.

Here you just want to define and use a command, but to allow use of row and column numbers, a simple wrapper command is used for defining and using the command for each cell.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\definecell[3]{\expandafter\def\csname tbl_#1_#2\endcsname{#3}}
\newcommand\tblcell[2]{\csname tbl_#1_#2\endcsname}

\begin{document}

\definecell{1}{1}{Text 1 1}
\definecell{1}{2}{Text 1 2}
\definecell{1}{3}{Text 1 3}
\definecell{10}{1}{last row 1}
\definecell{10}{2}{last row 2}
\definecell{10}{3}{last row 3}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c |}
 \tblcell{1}{1} & \tblcell{1}{2} & \tblcell{1}{3} \\ 
 \tblcell{10}{1}  & \tblcell{10}{2} & \tblcell{10}{3}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}



\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you! it worked